# MediaWiki Visual Editor support in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, mediawiki

I have installed Visual Editor on a MediaWiki installation. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, I haven't tested in Safari yet, but since it's the same engine as Chrome I guess it's okay. However in Internet Explorer 10 the tab is missing, I can only access the Wiki code edtitor. I can see, when I Google, that there have been some bugfixes due to Internet Explorer, so I'm surprised that it isn't working now. Do I need to do something in order to make it working?

I installed MediaWiki last week, so it's the newest version.

Also I get this as  class: 've-not-available'. Where MediaWiki.org has: 've-available ve-activated'. If I manually change it to vs-available in the inspector console, it's working.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: I have this in Internet Explorer 'HTML1300: Navigation occurred.' I'm suspecting that I might need to set prefershttps to 0 instead of 1? But I'm not sure where.

Comment: * I have added this comment as a part of the question, see last line *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 started being officially supported only a couple of weeks ago, thus to get it working on your wiki you'll need to install latest versions of VisualEditor, its dependencies, and MediaWiki from Git. Which is not recommended as bleeding edge is always bleeding edge. So the recommended strategy would be to wait for a stable release. Which might also have support for IE10 and 9.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have an idea when a stable release will be out for VisualEditor with IE11 support? I know it's a difficult question to ask, or maybe you can direct me to the page where I can see it when it is. I know they will keep bugging me at work about this until I have found a solution for Internet Explorer.

Comment: About the link I guess it's this one: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor/status#2014-09-04_.28MW_1.24wmf20.29

Comment: MW 1.24 has been branched today, it means that you might expect a stable release in a couple months.

Comment: I think that is the answer to my problem. Thanks.